# Fixing z column error when geometry has no z geometry

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, postgis, psycopg2, geopandas

I get the following error when writing a geopandas dataframe to PostGIS in a loop operation (the full code is included at the end)

`psycopg2.errors.InvalidParameterValue: Column has Z dimension but geometry does not`

The relevant code:
`gdf.to_postgis(name=tbl, con=engine, schema=gdb_name, if_exists='replace')`

How do I remove the z dimension from the column? Some logic like:

```
if geom has no z dimension and column has z dimension:
  alter column remove z dimension
```

I'd rather stay in sqlalchemy rather than using psycopg2 and sql `ALTER COLUMN` syntax.

I already have a get out for when a gdf is empty.

Full code:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateSchema

if not engine.dialect.has_schema(engine, gdb_name):
    engine.execute(CreateSchema(gdb_name))

# loop through each layer in the layerlist
for layer in layerlist:
    # reads all layers into a dictionary
    layers[layer] = gpd.read_file(COPA_gdb, driver="FileGDB", layer=layer)
    gdf = layers[layer]
    if gdf.empty:
        print(layer + ' dataFrame is empty! Not imported')
    else:
        tbl = layer.lower()
        print(tbl)
        gdf.to_postgis(name=tbl, con=engine, schema=gdb_name, if_exists='replace')
```

Comment: Current work around is to return to arcgis, use the copy tool and uncheck the z value box. The above code is in it's own env so no access to arcpy.

Comment: what kind of geometry is it? With a geodataframe, each row has a shapely object as its geometry

Comment: basically, you need to remove all of the code dealing with your database in this example. start with a representative geodataframe with maybe 5 rows and simplified geometries

Comment: @PaulH in this case it is polyline data, but it could be point or polygon also. Essentially I have a gdf, say 'roads' and it has a geometry column, in the gdf geom = `MULTILINESTRING Z ((477195.399 215965.386 76.2...`. As you see it has z geometry, so I'm unsure how to trouble shoot this one.

Comment: Build a minimal, reproducible example (by hand with about 5 very simple geometries) and then we'll get you on your way. But the the database connection has nothing to do with your problem. Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with this problem here too. In my case, I had empty geometries, inside my geodataframe. To fix it, I had to remove empty geometries, doing like this:

```
gdf = gdf[gdf.is_empty==False]
```

Using this I could solve this problem.

---

Actually, the previous code worked for a specific purpose, the better way I found to solve this problem is using the following lines:

```
func = lambda geom: shapely.wkb.loads(shapely.wkb.dumps(geom, output_dimension=2))
gdf['geometry'] = gdf['geometry'].apply(func)
```